# open cv ios video processing

Tags: ios, opencv, frameworks

I'm trying to do the tutorial found [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html) for ios video processing with openCv framework.

I've successfully loaded the ios openCv framework to my project - **but** there seems to be a mismatch between my framework and the one presented in the tutorial and I am hoping someone can help me.

OpenCv uses `cv::Mat` type for representing images. When using AVfoundation delegation to process images from the camera - I will need to convert all the `CMSampleBufferRef` to that type.

It seems that the openCV framework presented in the tutorial provides a library called using

```
#import <opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>
```

with a new delegate command:

Can anyone point me where I can find this framework or possibly fast conversion between `CMSampleBufferRef` and `cv::Mat`

**EDIT**

There is a lot of segmentation in the opencv framework (at least for ios). I've downloaded it through various "official" sites and also using tools such as fink and brew using THEIR instructions. I even compared header files that were installed to /usr/local/include/opencv/. They were different each time. When downloading an openCV project - there are various cmake files and conflicting readme files in the same project. I think I was successful in building a good version for IOS with avcapture functionality built in to the framework (with this header `<opencv2/highgui/cap_ios.h>`) through this [link](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv#readme)  and then building the library using the python script in the ios directory - using the command `python opencv/ios/build_framework.py ios`. I will try and update

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the conversion that I use.  You lock the pixel buffer, create a cv::Mat, process with the cv::Mat, then unlock the pixel buffer.

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );

int bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
int bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
int bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer);
unsigned char *pixel = (unsigned char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(bufferHeight,bufferWidth,CV_8UC4,pixel, bytesPerRow); //put buffer in open cv, no memory copied
//Processing here

//End processing
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress( pixelBuffer, 0 );
}
```

The above method does not copy any memory and as such you do not own the memory, pixelBuffer will free it for you.  If you want your own copy of the buffer, just do

```
cv::Mat copied_image = image.clone();
```

Comment: where is the pixelBuffer coming from? do you have any code to refer me to using avfoundation and openCV with the delegate captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:

Comment: The following code will not work at least on iPhone 6 and iPhone6+ with iOS 10.2 that I have tested because the underlying pixel array isn't continuous in the memory. Please see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 7):

This is the updated version of the code in the previous accepted answer which should work with any iOS device.

Since `bufferWidth` is not equal to `bytePerRow` at least on iPhone 6 and iPhone 6+, we need to specify the number of byte in each rows as the last argument to the cv::Mat constructor.

```
CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);

CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);

int bufferWidth = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer);
int bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer);
int bytePerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer);
unsigned char *pixel = (unsigned char *) CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer);
cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(bufferHeight, bufferWidth, CV_8UC4, pixel, bytePerRow); 

// Process you cv::Mat here

CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, 0);
```

The code has been tested on my iPhone5, iPhone6 and iPhone6+ running iOS 10.