# Copy cv::Mat into CMSampleBufferRef

Tags: ios, opencv, avfoundation

How can I copy cv::Mat data back into the sampleBuffer?

My scenario as follow : 
I create a cv::Mat from pixelBuffer for landmark detection and add the landmarks to cv::Mat image data. I'd like to copy this cv::Mat into the sample buffer to be shown with the landmark.

Is this possible ?

I achieved this with dlib but need to know how to do it with cv::mat:

```
char *baseBuffer = (char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
img.reset();
long position = 0;
while (img.move_next()) {
        dlib::bgr_pixel& pixel = img.element();
        long bufferLocation = position * 4; //(row * width + column) * 4;
        char b = baseBuffer[bufferLocation];
        char g = baseBuffer[bufferLocation + 1];
        char r = baseBuffer[bufferLocation + 2];
        dlib::bgr_pixel newpixel(b, g, r);
        pixel = newpixel;

        position++;
    }
```

Comment: Probably yes. A few more details? Some code?

Comment: I follow this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12355675/3649485) to convert `CVImageBufferRef` to cv::mat. 

now I'd like to put this cv::mat back into the sample buffer. I know how to do it with dlib by copying pixels to back into the sampleBuffer but don't know how to do it with openCV 

Sample code for dlib  in next comment

Comment: Please post the code properly formatted into the question. It not readable in a comment

Comment: It seems code highlighting is not working in comments I'll edit the main question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering my own question.

First thing, you need to access the pixel data of cv::mat Image, I followed this great [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7903042/3649485)

Then you need to copy pixel into the buffer starting from the basebuffer. Following code should help you achieve this :

```
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
char *baseBuffer = (char *)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);   
long position = 0;
uint8_t* pixelPtr = (uint8_t*)targetImage.data;
int cn = targetImage.channels();
cv::Scalar_<uint8_t> rgbPixel;
for(int i = 0; i < targetImage.rows; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < targetImage.cols; j++)
    {
        long bufferLocation = position * 4;

        rgbPixel.val[0] = pixelPtr[i*targetImage.cols*cn + j*cn + 0]; // B
        rgbPixel.val[1] = pixelPtr[i*targetImage.cols*cn + j*cn + 1]; // G
        rgbPixel.val[2] = pixelPtr[i*targetImage.cols*cn + j*cn + 2]; // R
        baseBuffer[bufferLocation] = rgbPixel.val[2];
        baseBuffer[bufferLocation + 1] = rgbPixel.val[1];
        baseBuffer[bufferLocation + 2] = rgbPixel.val[0];
        position++;
    }
}
```

Some things to take note of

- make sure you `CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress` and
  `CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress` before and after the operation.  I
- am doing this on `CV_8UC3`, you might want to check your cv::mat
  type.
- I haven't done the performance analysis but I am getting smooth output with this.

Comment: why `CV_8UC3`? `CMSampleBuffer` itself has 4 channels

Comment: yeah this method quite eats cpu, if don't have many functions in your app then it will be smooth, but if you have a lot of functions you are interesting in cpu usage

Comment: for me `worked` next solution `baseBuffer[bufferLocation] = pixelPtr[i*targetImage.cols*cn + j*cn + 0];
            baseBuffer[bufferLocation + 1] = pixelPtr[i*targetImage.cols*cn + j*cn + 1];
            baseBuffer[bufferLocation + 2] = pixelPtr[i*targetImage.cols*cn + j*cn + 2];` I guess it because I use `videoOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String) : NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA as UInt32)]`